# Solve this Nan issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a counter but a run on some issues, here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.counter1-up').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">50+</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">48+</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>

                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">1252+</span>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">171+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue with jQuery or JS? I know that I can solve this with CSS and HTML but I want to do it with JS code.
What will be best approach to solve this?
Thank you all

Comment: You haven't told us what the issue is. We're supposed to guess _and_ solve it?

Comment: The `step` method should return a result.  such as `return Math.ceil(now)`.  It shouldn't try to directly change the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your text, e.g. `50+` cannot be converted into a number. A quick fix will be to move the `+` outside of the `<span>` element where the number tweening will happen:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.counter1-up').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="far fa-calendar"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">50</span>+
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">48</span>+
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>

                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">1252</span>+

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-card">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <span data-toggle="counter1-up" class="counter1-up">171</span>+
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```